# Windows 10 Geofencing not rising events

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, geofencing

I am not able to get the GeofenceMonitor rising any event; neither StatusChanged nor GeofenceStateChanged. 
I am developing for Windws 10 - Build 14393.

Does it maybe depend on the device? Are there any hidden system settings that I have to enable first?

Comment: look if you also see the same on Creators Update 1703 - Build 15063.250

Comment: Have you receive any exception from the `GeofenceMonitor`?